# why my flask-pagedown can't has a newline why I write code by markdown?

Tags: python, flask

[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gn6ar.png)
like this,it use `{{ pagedown.include_pagedown() }}` to preview,but it can't have a newline,why and how to solve ?
Here's my code.

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'post'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True,default=datetime.utcnow)
    head = db.Column(db.String(64),index=True)
    item_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('items.id'))
    body_html = db.Column(db.Text)
    @staticmethod
    def on_changed_body(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
        allowed_tags = ['a', 'abbr', 'acronym', 'b', 'code', 'blockquote','em', 'i',          'strong','li','ol','pre','strong','ul','h1','h2','h3','p']
        target.body_html = bleach.linkify(bleach.clean(
            markdown(value, output_format='html'),
            tags=allowed_tags, strip=True)
            )
    db.event.listen(Post.body, 'set', Post.on_changed_body)
```

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CODE BLOCKS

Pre-formatted code blocks are used for writing about programming or markup source code. Rather than forming normal paragraphs, the lines of a code block are interpreted literally. Markdown wraps a code block in both  and  tags.
***To produce a code block in Markdown, simply indent every line of the block by at least 4 spaces or 1 tab***. I added the source of the answer below, so you can also check other syntax methods of markdown.

Source: https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode